# I keep getting IM002 Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager Data Source Name Not Found via my VS2008 application

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting IM002 Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager Data Source Name Not Found via my VS2008 application. 
Code:

```
Friend sConnString As String = "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DefaultDir=" + DriveLetter + " hamradio;DBQ=" + DriveLetter + "hamradio\hflogdb.accdb"
Friend con = New Odbc.OdbcConnection(sConnString)
Friend cmd As New OdbcCommand
Friend scon

Public Sub GetData() 
'If Database is open then close it to reset the ODBC System Table Resource' 
       If constate = "Open" Then
           con.Close()
           constate = con.State.ToString
       End If

        Dim dr As OdbcDataReader        
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        constate = con.State.ToString
        strSQL10 = "select * from NAME where NAM =('" + NAMTEXTBOX.Text.ToUpper + "')"
        Dim sqlcmd10 As New OdbcCommand(strSQL10, con)
        dr = sqlcmd10.ExecuteReader()
```

```
ODBC DRIVER SETUP:
USER DSN           Platform    Driver 
MS Access Database 32 bit      Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, accdb)
```

Can someone show me the code I need to do to get the code listed to work with WIN 10??

Comment: I don't think the connection string you're using actually requires a DSN to be created. (It's called a DSNless connection). This can be trucly to troubleshoot. Here are bunch of other connection strings to try: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ Just make absolutely sure that the path to the MDB is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question.

Comment: You posted the following:

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;

Comment: What would my Provider be and where would I find that information?? Would my provider be the USER DSN "MS ACCESS DATABASE" ??

Comment: The very first thing is to come up with a working connection string. To do that, follow the instructions here: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1D5EB4DCBD13106486256B9D005E11B0. Forget about all the references to LabView- you just want to connect to your mdb file. Start at **2. Select New, then Text Document.** in this page. Press the _Test Connection_ button to make sure you can connect. Once you've done that, press OK, and open your .UDL file in notepad and there is your correct connection string.

Comment: I created the udl file and Windows 10 returns the following under providers:  "Microsoft OLEDB provider for ODBC DRIVERS" When I click on it it gives me selection box that asks for Data Source Name. I point to th Data Source that says "MS Access Database". When I click on the box that says use "Connection String" then I point to the Database and click ok the following error is returned: "operation can not be executed because an error occurred during connection to the driver"  What am I doing wrong. The screen pics on the web page and what windows 10 shows do not match.

Comment: I avoid ODBC and use ACE or Jet drivers. Do you have ACE (or Access Database Engine) in your list? Are you able to open the access file directly?

Comment: The list contains:

Comment: The list contains:  The list contains:   Microsoft OLEDB provider for ODBC DRIVERS, OLEDB Provider for search, OLEDB Provider for SQL SERVER, OLEDB for Simple Provider, MS Data Shape, Provider for Microsoft Directory Services and SQL Native Chat.      BTW, I'm using Access 2010. Access will open Database but VB gives an error.

Comment: You could install the ACE driver from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and try using that. With regards to your errors it's difficult to tell but it could be related to a 32 bit / 64 bit problem.

Comment: Nick, will download and try. Will let you know if it works. We have had to deal with Mathew the past couple of days. Have some time now to try.

Comment: Installed jet engine and it doesn't appear under list of providers. Install didn't seem to have any issues. Don't know why it doesn't appear in provider list. Windows 10 is a pain.

Comment: Drivers not existing after install makes me think it might be a 32 / 64 bit thing. Can you try this and see if your driver appears? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaitanya_medikonduri/2008/04/09/how-to-run-32-bit-udl-file-on-a-64-bit-operating-system/ . Sorry I don't have a solution to your actual problem at this stage.

Comment: got it to create:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\HAMRADIO\hflogdb.accdb;Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False in UDL File. BTW, Test Connection Worked, However, If I click on the file displayed in file explorer to open it, it returns the following "Provider Cannot be Found"

Comment: Ensure that provider has been installed. I don't get it. If I run "C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile C:\HAMRADIO\test.udl" it opens the UDL and lets me test the connection.

Comment: Error happens when file is being opened by OLE DB Core Services.

Comment: If I open it with notepad I see the generated connection.

Comment: I thought this would install driver for OLEDB (this what the link said to run to create 32 bit udl) "C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll",OpenDSLFile C:\HAMRADIO\test.udl "

Comment: Still getting error with vs2008 vb.

Comment: We're probably getting a bit off track but what you're seeing is 32/64 bit thing. Sounds like the 32 bit driver is installed, which is why the syswow64 bit works (things in syswow64 folder are... 32bit! go figure!). However when you double click it it opens the 64 bit version of the UDL program, and it can't find the 64 bit version of the driver. Easiest thing is to make sure both the 64 bit and 32 bit versions are installed. You mention windows 10 a lot - was your prior operating system 32 bit by any chance? If this worked before it really helps to describe the circumstances

Comment: My previous OS was Windows 7 (32 bit).  When I tried to install the 64 bit driver, I get a message that says, "Your version of Windows office that's installed in 32 bit, not 64 bit." Should I de install my office 2010 and install the 64 bit driver for access then reinstall my office 2010?? I'm confused

Comment: Does your VS2008 application run as 32 bit or 64 bit? First work that out. If it runs as 64 bit then you need a 64 driver to connect to MS Access. However the 64 bit ACE driver will _not_ install if you have office 32 bit installed. So... sorry this has been such a journey but they key to understanding is to at all times know if you are running as 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: To put it another way, you can only install one version of office (32 bit or 64 bit). _Also_ the ACE driver must match the version of office. So if you are certain you need the 64 bit ACE driver (i.e. if your app runs as 64 bit), then you need to uninstall office 32bit, theni nstall office 64 bit, then install ACE 64 bit. Then your 64 bit application will be able to access the ACE 64 bit driver

Comment: I bought a new computer from Dell as the old one went South. I was told that Dell only built 64 bit machines now. My old one was 32 bit. The new one came with Win 10 the old one had Win 7. My version of Office was 2010 32 bit. My version of VS2008 was 32 bit. Yes everything I moved from my backup to the new machine was 32bit.

Comment: Yes my application is 32 bit. I still get the IM002 Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager Data Source Name Not Found via my VS2008 application. Code when I run it. I  tried what you suggested and I still get "IM002 Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager Data Source Name Not Found via my VS2008 application. Code". I have installed the 32 bit driver that you pointed me too and tried to install the 64 bit too.

Comment: I'm at my wits end here and I don't know what to do next. The Access 2010 application runs fine. The problem is VS2008 will not run Access.

Comment: I understand your frustration! Since we can't get ACE working perhaps we need to go back to ODBC. Can you open the 32 bit ODBC admin (c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe). Then, can you successfully create and test a system DSN that points to your MS Access file? Then there is a way to get the connection string out of that and reuse it.

Comment: This page: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ contains a bunch of sample ODBC connection strings under the heading "Microsoft Access ODBC Driver". It might be that your upgraded OS requires a _slightly_ different string. Assuming your system DSN test works from the previous step, try it all again but this time crate a file DSN, then go and open the file you created and you should be able to find the correct value for the DRIVER part. It's quite possible that your new install of windows doesn't have this ODBC driver installed, or it has a slightly different name